# Using :target pseudo class for css animation

Tags: css, svg, css-selectors, css-animations

I'm trying to make an svg icon clickable to trigger an animation for a svg box. 
I have no problems making the bubble move when with the :active pseudoclass but once I add :target on, nothing works.

Here's how my css looks

```
#calendar .calendartab  {
cursor: pointer;
transform-origin: 50% 50%;
transform: translateY(10px);
transition-duration: 0.3s;
transition-timing-function: ease-in-out forwards;
}

#calendar .calendartab:target {
transform: translateY(200px);
}
```

---

Here's some of my code on jsfiddle 
    http://jsfiddle.net/phantomboogie/khzrn3b6/

Comment: ref: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_target.asp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - include current output vs expected output, as removing the ':target' from your code did make a change and its unclear what you want as the 'clickable button' does nothing even without ':target'

Comment: If it’s relevant, your fiddle has a closing `</a>` but no opening tag. Since `:target` is tied to the URI, did you intend to have the link point to an id?

Comment: I missed a few lines of code. I'm trying to be able to click on the icon and have the white bubble come down. I added a href for the icon and pointed it towards the box

Comment: I see that a lot of the target examples use div ids, is that the same as g id? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think I get the concept of how this works when I'm hiding and setting a list as a target, but am confused due to my objects all being svgs

Comment: For this to work, you would need an anchor with this elements id as the target, I don't see this anywhere in your code?